# Java Spring MVC PRG Pattern preserve Data on reload

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i'm currently woking on a spring mvc project. I have a page with a form, which represents a configurator.
The user can choose some data in a bunch of select fields and proceeds to the next step, where he gets the same jsp-page but with some more fields, depending on his inputs he made. This will be repeated a few times until he gets his result on another page. Each time a POST will be performed.

Now if the user uses the back function of the Browser he doesn't get to the previous page, but to a browser default "broken page", where Chrome for example says something like "Please confirm resubmission of the form data...". To actually resubmit the data he has to press reload and confirm a popup.

The resubmission itself isn't really a problem, because the data does not get inconsistent, it just performs another call to the backend and receives the data it provides.
The real no-go is the fact that the user has to manually refresh the page and by chance gets confused by the default browser page.

I did some research and found out, that the [PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) might solve this problem.
In fact i can now navigate through the browser or reload the page and does not get the popup or broken page - because it's now a GET request of course.

The problem now is, that if i navigate back, the last page does not contain the data it contained before, but is now empty because no data at all is existing.
I understand that it is now a GET request and no data gets posted, but i thought the previous page  would be "reused", like shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get#/media/File:PostRedirectGet_DoubleSubmitSolution.png).

Now with the PRG-Pattern the handling of the application is even worse, because if the user reloads or navigates back, he basically has to start from scratch.

Did i misunderstood the meaning of this Pattern?

A quick look into some code, how i implemented this:

```
@PostMapping("/config")
public String handlePostRequestConfig(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, ProductForm productForm){
    //Handle productForm and add additional content to it
    if(noMoreStepsLeft){
        return "redirect:/result";
    }
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("form", productForm);
    return "redirect:/config";
}
@GetMapping("/config")
public String handleGetRequestConfig(Model model, @ModelAttribute("form") ProductForm productForm{
    model.addAttribute("form", productForm);
    return getJsp("product");
}
```

Inside JSP:

```
<form method="post" action="/config">
    <c:foreach items="${form.selectFields}" var="selectField">
        <input...>
    </c:foreach>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [*PRG*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), `P` is not the first step of user action flow. *PRG* is a part of the full flow.

The following shows a flow and how *PRG* fits in it:

User will hit a URL. For example: `http://localhost:8080/myContextPath/config`.
This will be handled using a `GET` handler:

```java
@GetMapping("/config")
public String show(ModelMap model) {
    // code
    
    model.put("form", productForm);
    return "product";    // returning view name which will be resolved by a view resolver
}
```

*product.jsp*:

```jsp
<form commandName="form" method="post">
    <c:foreach items="${form.selectFields}" var="selectField">
        <input...>
    </c:foreach>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This *submit* action will be handled by a **`POST`** handler:

```java
@PostMapping("/config")
public String submit(@ModelAttribute("form") ProductForm productForm, 
                     RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    
    // code, may be service calls, db actions etc

    return "redirect:/config";
}
```

This **redirect** to `/config` will be handled again by `/config` **`GET`** handler. (Or you can redirect to any `GET` handler of course)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But don't i lose the data when i reload or navigate trough the browser, too? Thats my main problem...

Comment: You mean after posting a form? or before that?

Comment: after posting the form / after i get redirected

Comment: After handling `POST`, a logical unit of work is considered to be completed. You should move a new `GET` handler to do what you need to no next. And redirect does the chaining between `POST` and  a new `GET`. So, you should design in such a way that your task is finished within the `POST`. That is the paradigm. (You can use `RedirectAttributes` to send data like success messages using flash maps with redirect).